# Cannot update RokSprocket Module 2.1.x to latest 2.1.24

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, update

I'm having a issue with a module update in Joomla.
I cannot update from RokSprocket Module 2.1.x to latest 2.1.24

I am getting the error on trying to update

> Error
>
> RokSprocket needs at least RokCommon version 3.2.6. You currently have RokCommon version 3.2.5
>
> Warning
>
> Extension Update: Custom install routine failure.

Any advice?

Comment: thx fixed my posting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happened recently on a website I was working on.

You can download and install manually the RokCommon update from https://rockettheme.com/joomla/extensions/rokutilities

Comment: where is not autoupdate available?

Comment: @cilap apparently something isn't working as expected - because if it would, you wouldn't had come here asking the question. That's life...

Comment: RokCommon can also be downloaded when you download RokSprocket at https://rockettheme.com/joomla/extensions/roksprocket